# Change Emmet shortcut key

Tags: dreamweaver, emmet

The "expand abbreviation" shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> by default in Dreamweaver. How can I change it to Tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Edit -> keyboard shortcuts` , `commands = menu commands` , and go to `commands -> Emmet -> expand abbreviation` 
you can change it to a Unsaved shortcut key  (except : 'tab' , ...) .

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Expand Abbreviation keyboard shortcut and make the new command Ctrl+Tab.

Then just highlight the Ctrl+ part, right click and Cut.

Then Tab remains! The only issue with changing this shortcut to tab is that now tab will not work for tabbing. If you can stand that you can use tab with emmet. You could use Ctrl+Alt+[ for indenting.

Answer (score 1):

### Create a new Keyboard Shortcut set for Emmet

By default, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut is set up for Dreamweaver's Tag Chooser, which supercedes Emmet's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. We'll fix this by removing the keyboard shortcut for the Tag Chooser.

1. Go to `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts…`
2. Under *Current set*, choose *Dreamweaver Standard* (selected by default if you haven't changed it) or another preferred set.
3. Click on the *Duplicate set* button on the right. (You can't simply edit the default set).
4. Rename the set. (ex. "Dreamweaver for Emmet")
5. In the *Commands* window, go to `Insert > Tag…`
6. Remove `Ctrl+E` from the *Shortcuts* window by clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> button.
7. Click *OK*.

Now the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut is freed up to work for Emmet's *Expand Abbreviation* command.

If desired, you may also change the shortcut for *Expand Abbreviation*:

In the Keyboard Shortcuts edit window, with your newly created set selected, navigate to `Commands > Emmet > Expand Abbreviation`. Press the key combination you would like to use.

Alternatively, you can type a key or key combination into a text editor (ex. literally type `Tab` or `Ctrl+E`), copy it, then paste it in the *Press key* text field by right-clicking and choosing paste. If you try to paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it will record `Ctrl+V` as the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

According to user reports, you can’t override Tab key with `Keyboard Shortcuts` dialog in Dreamweaver. So this issue should be addressed to DW developers.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Tab in Notepad and copy. Now, in changing shortcut keys section. click right mouse button and paste..but if u do that tab function will not work..it will only be for emmet and u cnt use tab for its original function